# Iptables, ipset, как запретить все, кроме необходимого? white list!

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, filter, блокировки

Есть линукс (убунту) сервер, в сервере надо фильтровать запрос по ИП лист (iplist.txt) точнее пропускать все исходящий и входящий трафик по iplist.txt (IP лист ) а остальных заблокировать! Заранее спасибо! В интернете что-то нашёл, как-то переделал но только не был((

```
iptables -P INPUT -j DROP 
iptables -P OUTPUT -j DROP
```

далее тут ipset

```
sudo wget -O /var/whitelist.txt http://kakoy-ta.sayt/whitelist.txt
while read ip; do
sudo ipset add WHITE_LIST $ip
done < /var/whitelist.tx
```

и ipset выдаёт ошибку

```
ipset v6.30: The set with  the given name does not exist
```

как добавить всех в iptable!?

```
iptables -A INPUT --src-list WHITE_LIST -j ALLOW
iptables -A OUTPUT --dst-list WHITE_LIST -j ALLOW
```

Comment: Ну вам же явно написали чего не хватает. Добавьте вначале цель WHITE_LIST в таблицу, потом уже добавляйте правила в неё.

Comment: а как добавить!? я не очень разбираюсь...
вроде цель это типо правил iptables!? или что то иной из ipset!?

Comment: http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html Читайте.

Comment: мне надо начало создать список с маской!?
ipset create WHITE_LIST hash:ip netmask 30
вроде так!?

Comment: Ну что-то подобное, да. `INTRODUCTION` как раз показывает что и за чем вызывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам ipset отвечает, что де списка нема, создайте словарик IP и настройте iptables:

```
sudo ipset create whitelist hash:net family inet hashsize 524288 maxelem 800000 counters comment

sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -I INPUT 2 -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT
```

и начинайте добавлять:

```
sudo ipset --add whitelist 41.231.136.121
```

или по-вашему:

```
while read -r ip; do sudo ipset --add whitelist $ip done < /var/whitelist.txt
```

Также можете [тутой](https://serverfault.com/questions/688424/how-to-blacklist-or-whitelist-lots-or-few-ip-ranges-with-ipset-and-iptables-fa) глянуть.

Comment: Отвечаю так поздно почти с 2 года разница но спасибо)

Comment: @mr.lostov обещанного ну вы помните)